# Issue Java 32/64bit in connecting R or Python to Oracle DB

Tags: java, oracle, 64-bit

my premise is that I am not an IT expert; I just understand the necessary.

I spent the last 4 hours researching on Google to try establish a connection or R/Python to Oracle Database.

I am using a Windows 10 laptop and running `java -version` on command prompt I see this:

```
java version "1.8.0_162"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_162-b12)
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 25.162-b12, mixed mode, sharing)
```

Then, the characteristics of the Oracle DB I want to connect to are the following:

```
Select * from v$version;

Oracle Database 12c EE High Perf Release 12.1.0.2.0 - 64bit Production
PL/SQL Release 12.1.0.2.0 - Production
"CORE   12.1.0.2.0  Production"
TNS for Linux: Version 12.1.0.2.0 - Production
NLSRTL Version 12.1.0.2.0 - Production
```

From what I understood, the bit version of Java must be the same as the version or R and Python, therefore, both 64-bit or both 32-bit.

Considering I would prefer using R o Python 64bit, do you think I can replace my current 32-bit Java version to a 64-bit or it will cause some kind of issues connecting to the Oracle DB (considering its characteristics)?

Comment: You can connect with a 32-bit Client to a 64-bit Database without any problem - and vice versa.

Comment: So if I want to change my java to 64-bit in order to use R or Python 64-bit, which java should I re-install? Java SE, SDK, ...?

Comment: What are you using Java for? If you're trying to connect R to Oracle use the *ROracle* driver; if you're trying to connect Python use *cx_Oracle*...

Comment: ROracle is not updated since many years I cannot use it on recent versions. Python cx_Oracle require java to be installed on your computer as well.